# How to create the Withdraw and Deposit in my work

Tags: java

```
public class Account {
    //===============Properties===================
    protected double Balance;
    protected String Owner;
    protected double AcctNo;

    //================Behaviors===============

    public void setBalance(double bal) {Balance = bal;}
    public double getBalance() {return Balance;}

    public void setOwner(String own) {Owner = own;}
    public String getOwner() {return Owner;}

    public void setAcctNo(double an) {AcctNo = an;}
    public double getAcctNo() {return AcctNo;}

    //==============Constructors==============
    public Account()  {
        super();
        Balance=0;
        Owner="";
        AcctNo=0;
    }

    public Account(double bal, String own, double an) {
        super();
        Balance=bal;
        Owner=own;
        AcctNo=an;
    }

    public void deposit() {
        0=deposit+Balance;
    }

    public void withdraw() {
        0=withdraw-Balance;
    }


    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Owner   = " + getOwner());
        System.out.println("Balance   = " + getBalance());
        System.out.println("Account Number   = " + getAcctNo());
    }


    public static void main (String args []) {
        Account a1;
        a1 = new Account();
        a1.setOwner("Frank");
        a1.setBalance(1000);
        a1.setAcctNo(2222);
        a1.deposit(100.00);
        a1.display();
    }
}
```

The withdraw and deposit has became tricky for me, I thought that, that would be the answer to solving the problem, but it was not. I believe everything else is finished except for the those 2 problems

Can I be guided towards the way to understanding the Deposit and Withdrawal concept please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: WTF is `0=deposit+Balance` supposed to mean? Furthermore, diposite and withdraw should receive a sum that you are going to deposit/withdraw. `deposit` has no meaning in your procedure. Finally, `double` is a bad type for money, http://www.google.ee/search?q=java+money+type

Comment: Wouldn't that be the reason why I'm asking the question? I tried but I don't understand how? I don't get it? Sorry?

Comment: We are not supposed to teach you the Java basics to the level you able to do your assignment. This assignment is obviously too high-grade for you. Take a first lesson on java before asking to do the homework for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems are here:

```
0=deposit+Balance;
```

and here:

```
0=withdraw-Balance;
```

When assigning values to variables in Java, the right hand side is evaluated and the result is stored in the left hand side, e.g.

```
result = things+to+add;
```

But your code attempts to calculate something and store the result in 0, a literal number, this cannot work, it needs to be a variable.

Also, you functions to withdraw and deposit - how much are you withdrawing or depositing? The deposit function needs to know how much to deposit, and the withdraw function needs to know how much to withdraw. You need to add an argument to each to provide this information:

Here's a possible deposit function:

```
public void deposit(double amount) {
  balance = balance+amount;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Heres some things you should all the time with your code

1. Use consistent formatting and make sure things are indented to the correct location. This means that if you have code inside brackets (`{}`) that they are  are indented 1 and only 1 tab in (tab or 4 space w/e...).
2. in Java classes are always started with an uppercase and non static final variables are started with lower case variables, the variables `Balance`, `Owner` and `AcctNo` would be more suitable to start with lower case characters.

If you follow those formatting steps it will be much easier to debug and read your code.

---

Now your problem is your `withdraw` and `deposit` methods for 1 dont have a variable in the arguments. You need to add a variable to the method signature.

```
public void deposit(double ammount) {....
```

Then you have the statement `0=deposit+Balance;` which I dont know what your intending to do there but it is invalid Java. It probably should read: `Balance=Balance+deposit`.